# What does the DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY and DOCKER_CERT_PATH variable do?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker, using boot2docker on Windows 7.
While I was trying to configure Docker build through spotify maven plugin, I was asked to set below env variables :

```
DOCKER_HOST
DOCKER_CERT_PATH
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
```

Configuration was successful but am not sure 
What does the  `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` and `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` variables do ?

Answer (score 3):

As [mentioned in the README](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/f2d5ca6c55da99084a2c0f104e0cdcdac01868f7/README.md#tls-support):

> **By default, boot2docker runs docker with TLS enabled**. It auto-generates certificates and stores them in `/home/docker/.docker` inside the VM.
>   The `boot2docker up` command will copy them to `~/.boot2docker/certs` on the host machine once the VM has started, and output the correct values for the `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` and `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` environment variables.

```
eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)" will also set them correctly.
```

> We strongly recommend against running Boot2Docker with an unencrypted Docker socket for security reasons, but if you have tools that cannot be easily switched, you can disable it by adding `DOCKER_TLS=no` to your `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` file.

In a more dynamic environment, where the boot2docker ip can change, see [issue 944](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/944).

Answer (score 2):

Please check below comments for now. I'm not a Go developer but I understand usage from it.
To be edited later as it is too Spartan.

from https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/3ea762b9f6ba256cf51bd2c35988f0c48bccf0b0/client/client.go

```
[...]
// Use DOCKER_HOST to set the url to the docker server.
// Use DOCKER_API_VERSION to set the version of the API to reach, leave empty for latest.
// Use DOCKER_CERT_PATH to load the tls certificates from.
// Use DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY to enable or disable TLS verification, off by default.
func NewEnvClient() (*Client, error) {
    var client *http.Client
    if dockerCertPath := os.Getenv("DOCKER_CERT_PATH"); dockerCertPath != "" {
        options := tlsconfig.Options{
            CAFile:             filepath.Join(dockerCertPath, "ca.pem"),
            CertFile:           filepath.Join(dockerCertPath, "cert.pem"),
            KeyFile:            filepath.Join(dockerCertPath, "key.pem"),
            InsecureSkipVerify: os.Getenv("DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY") == "",
[...]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? How could one really read the exact path from that code?