# Docker Toolbox on Windows: disable TLS

Tags: windows, docker

I installed Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 and it seems to work.
Now it is running on port 2376 with (I Suppose) TLS enabled

```
$ docker-machine ls
  NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER ERRORS
  default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v17.06.1-ce
```

I'd like to run on port 2375 with TLS disabled.

Is it possible (on Windows?)

I found a lot of suggestion but for Linux

Comment: Why? Is there a *valid* reason for this? Neither browsers nor programming languages have any problem working with TLS. Do you have a different problem perhaps and think that it's caused by TLS ?

Comment: Maybe. I am using Maven Docker plugin and I got

    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven- plugin:0.2.3:build (default-cli) on project HelloWorldJavaMicroService: Exception caught: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset -> [Help 1]

I read about possible TLS problem

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176262/what-does-the-docker-tls-verify-and-docker-cert-path-variable-do

Comment: Which say to *avoid* disabling TLS. Don't disable TLS. Did you try googling for the error? The very first result in a resolved issue in [the plubing repository](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/issues/51) and links to the [HTTPS instructions](https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/) for docker

Answer (score 12):

If you are running Windows 10 + Windows Subsystem for Linux + Ubuntu + Docker Toolbox make sure to add following lines (thanks @pacionet for help) to either `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 // your Docker IP
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/mnt/c/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/.docker/machine/certs
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

If you get any TLS related errors when using `docker-compose` later on, please make sure that you are using latest Docker Compose version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this configuration on MAVEN "Run Configuration" environment properties

```
DOCKER_CERT_PATH C:\Users\<username>\.docker\machine\certs
DOCKER_HOST tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY 1
```